# 'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: github, command-line, laravel, fortrabbit

I have been trying to deploy my app into the Fortrabbit servers using the command line. I'm using windows. Here is what I tried :

```
C:\projects\riwaya>git remote add fort git@git2.eu1.frbit.com:riwaya.git
C:\projects\riwaya>git remote fort
C:\projects\riwaya>ssh u-riwaya@ssh2.eu1.frbit.com
'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable     program or batch file.
```

I have watched [This Laracast Video](https://laracasts.com/lessons/fortrabbit-deploment-files)  and did the same as Jeffrey but it doesn't work ...

Can somebody help ?

Comment: You can ask the question on the `Laracast Forum` mentioning this video tutorial. maybe `Jeff` will help too.

Comment: You could install ssh with **chocolatey** by just doing `choco search ssh` then install the one you prefer. I'm not sure if this is outside the topic but for windows a package manager like `choco` can help you a lot with dev tools (like ssh).

Comment: Actually use putty on windows. It's windows native ssh agent.

Comment: check the environment path (git-base is set or not )

Answer (score 10):

Actually you have 2 problems here: First is that you don't have ssh installed, second is that you don't know how to deploy

### Install SSH

It seems that ssh is not installed on your computer.

You can install openssh from here : http://openssh.en.softonic.com/download

### Generate your key

Than you will have to geneate your ssh-key. There's a good tutorial about this here:

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows

### Deploy

To deploy, you just have to push your code over git. Something like this:

```
git push fort master
```

If you get permission denied, be sure that you have put your public_key in the dashboard in the git tab.

### SSH

The ssh command gives you access to your remote node. You should have received a password by email and now that you have ssh installed, you should be asked for a password when trying to connect. just input that password. If you want to use your private ssh key to connect to your server rather then typing that password, you can follow this : http://fortrabbit.com/docs/how-to/ssh-sftp/enable-public-key-authentication

Comment: I understand softonic also packages malwares along-with binaries.

Comment: Not softonic, please!

Answer (score 8):

For Windows, first install the git base from here: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Next, set the environment variable:

1. Press <kbd>Windows+R</kbd> and type sysdm.cpl
2. Select advance -> Environment variable
3. Select path-> edit the path and paste the below line:

> ```
> C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe
> ```

To test it, open the command window: press <kbd>Windows+R</kbd>, type cmd and then type ssh.

Comment: path may vary on system config. Is that path is valid?

Answer (score 4):

First of all Go to browser and install openssh here: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases

Next step, extract rar file into folder and then copy and paste it in your drive.
after that run command: ssh it should work.

Next step is right click on shh in openssh folder and go to properties. Copy the path
and paste it in system variables in edit environment variables.
It will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR, add this to `settings.json`

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows":
{
        "PATH": "C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH",
},
```

Just found a case when the integrated terminal hasn't recognized 'ssh' as command, but you tried 'ssh' that was working on external terminals like CMD, git-bash.

That means you didn't add PATH variable to your integrated terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for solution even now, here is how I did it for my Windows 10 machine.

1. Start > type '*Manage Optional Features*'
2. Add Feature [+]
3. Look for OpenSSH client & select & install
4. After successful installation, open (close if already opened) powershell or command prompt and run **ssh**!

Comment: this is an easy and clean solution, but the download always fails for me. Hope it works for someone else