# Symfony deploy by Easy Deploy Bundle SSH

Tags: symfony, ssh, symfony4

Im trying to deploy my Symfony App using Easy Deploy Bundle.
But after run command `php bin/console deploy stable` error occuerd:

```
The command "cd D:\MySymfonyApp && where ssh" failed.  
Exit Code: 1(General error)                           
Working directory: D:\MySymfonyApp                     
Output:                                                            
================                                                   
Error Output:                                                      
================                                                   
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

The ssh config in my opinion is ok. (the `cd D:\MySymfonyApp && where ssh` returns `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`

I try to run this on Windows 10. (symfony 4.1)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your session variables are not setted and ssh binary is not found.

[You can fix them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158177/ssh-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command?answertab=votes#tab-top) or...

My advice is [to install ubuntu's terminal inside your Windows 10.](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows)

You'll find your files at /mount

```
cd /mnt/d
```

I am currently [using deployer.org](https://deployer.org/) and I am completely happy with it, it has a lot of recipies for Laravel/Symfony and you can fire Telegram or Slack notifications when a new deploy is done. (and a lot of more things)